# Show that $\sum_{z=1, \, z|n}^n z^2 \mu(z/n) = n \phi(n) \prod_{p|n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{p} \right)$

Tags: number-theory

Show that $$\sum_{z=1, \, z|n}^n z^2 \mu(z/n) = n \phi(n) \prod_{p|n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{p} \right).$$

I have no idea how to show this. I tried different things for few hours and now Im out of ideas really..

Here $\mu(z)$ is möbius function and $\phi(z)$ is euler's totient.

Comment: What's $\mu(z)$?

Comment: @Myath Added in OP. Its möbius function.

Comment: Prove both sides are multiplicative and evaluate on prime powers.

Comment: @Asvin Well Im not really given the right side, just trying to get there..

Comment: You can still usually guess the answer and use what I said. Another thing you can do is note that the left hand side is a Dirichlet composition, find the zeta functions of the series involved and try to rearrange the euler products. This is the same idea as evaluating on prime powers but might be a bit easier(or harder) to see.

Comment: How about going in the other direction? Start with the right hand side, and arrive at the left.

Comment: @Asvin Well tbh I even have problems evaluation both sides of prime powers and showing they are equal..

Comment: Well, for prime powers, the left hand side only has two terms and the right hand side is easy to evaluate. What is the problem you are having for prime powers?

Comment: @Asvin Maybe Im just too tired but the left hand side is the problem..

Comment: I could do this one but if Daniel Fischer is working on it I prefer to wait.

Comment: @Asvin I got $p^{2k}-p^{2k-2}$ from the right..

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Go ahead. It's too late at night for me to type a whole answer now.

Comment: @Asvin And I got $1-p^2$ from left.. It seems Im doing a mistake somewhere

Comment: You are correct. The identity as stated is wrong. It should be $\sum_{z|n}z^2\mu(n/z)$ on the left.

Comment: @Azvin Ah then I have a mistake somewhere at my calculations before.. And I can see the answer to this post now, thanks.

Comment: @Nklups It should be $\mu(n/z)$, not $\mu(z/n)$.

Comment: Definitely correct this.

Answer (score 2):

In the following we assume that $$n=\prod_{p|n} p^v$$ is the prime factorization of $n$ and use the Euler product
$$\zeta(s)=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-1/p^s}.$$

The Dirichlet series for the left is a convolution of
$$\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{q^2}{q^s} = \zeta(s-2)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{\mu(q)}{q^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}.$$

Therefore this Dirichlet series is
$$\frac{\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(s)}.$$

On the other hand the right is
$$n^2 \prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)
= \prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) p^{2v}.$$

The Euler product here is
$$\prod_p \left(1+\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) \sum_{q\ge 1}\frac{p^{2q}}{p^{qs}}\right)$$

or $$\prod_p \left(1+\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) 
\frac{1/p^{s-2}}{1-1/p^{s-2}}\right)$$

which is
$$\prod_p \frac{1}{1-1/p^{s-2}}
\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s-2}} + \frac{1}{p^{s-2}}-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)
\\ = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-1/p^{s-2}}
\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right).$$

This simplifies to the Dirichlet series $$\frac{\zeta(s-2)}{\zeta(s)}.$$

The LHS is the same as the RHS, done.

**Remark I.** The equation $$\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{\mu(q)}{q^s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$$ follows from the Euler product $$\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{\mu(q)}{q^s} = \prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right).$$

**Remark II.** The simplification of the RHS follows from
$$\varphi(n) = n \prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem:** If $f$ is multiplicative and $F$ is the summatory function of $f$, then$$
f(n) = \sum_{z\mid n} \mu(n/z)F(z).$$

Let $\displaystyle f(n) = n\phi(n)\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right) = \prod_{p\mid n}p^{2e}-p^{2e-2}$; $e$ is the largest power of prime $p$ dividing $n$.

Then $\displaystyle F(n) = \sum_{z\mid n}\prod_{p\mid z}p^{2k}-p^{2k-2}$ where $k$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $z$. So $1\le k\le e$.

The result will follow from the theorem above if $F(n) = n^2$.

Let $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\dots p_r^{e_r}$, and 
$$
\begin{align*}
n^2 &= p_1^{2e_1}p_2^{2e_2}\dots p_r^{2e_r} =\prod_{1\le i\le r}p_i^{2e_i} \\
&= \prod_{1\le i\le r}(1+(p_i^2-1)+(p_i^4-p_i^2)+\dots +(p_i^{2e_i}-p_i^{2e_i-2})).
\end{align*}
$$
If the last product is expanded, it gives the sum of $1$ ($1\mid n$) and all possible products
$\displaystyle\prod_{} p^{2k}-p^{2k-2}$, which is exactly the same as $\displaystyle F(n) = \sum_{z\mid n}\prod_{p\mid z}p^{2k}-p^{2k-2}$. Maybe someone can please help me explain this better.